# How to hide a div in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide a div with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375449/how-to-hide-a-div-with-jquery)

Is there any way to hide the content of div in css without using the display: none; 
because it remove the object from code.

I also used the visibility: hidden;
but the image content of div still display

Comment: use position:absolute and left:-100000, btw display: none; never remove any object?

Comment: read it http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm

Comment: i also has used the position and top- but it still breaks the jquery events that continuously running...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107917/hide-a-div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375449/how-to-hide-a-div-with-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375449/how-to-hide-a-div-with-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319279/how-to-hide-div-that-without-id-class-by-jquery etc etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Place the contents inside of a inner div and set that inner div to display none.

Comment: I can't use the display: none because it breaks the jquery events

Answer (score 1):

Set visibility to hidden and *don't* set the visibility of the descendants (the images that are showing up) to visible.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can do

```
$('div').hide();
```

If you want to be more specific you can use an id or class name instead if div.

ex: `$('#myid').hide();`

Comment: .hide() is equivalent to .css('display', 'none')

Comment: question was for .css not jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can store the contents in temporary and then do empty, restore these content to the DIV when you need.

```
var contents= $('divId').html();
$('divId').html('');
```

Comment: because the content is dynamic and running a script continuously so i can't do it